# Paypal Adaptive Payment Fees

Tags: api, paypal

I am testing Adaptive Chained and Parallel Payments Sandbox API on my Fiverr Clone gigs site.
Why do both the receivers, the site owner and the gig host, get charged with a fee?
How do I change it so that only I get the fee and send it to the gig host without having them get charged?

Answer (score 1):

Use the feesPayer element in your Pay request.

> xs:string (Optional) The payer of PayPal fees. Allowable values are:
>
> SENDER – Sender pays all fees (for personal, implicit simple/parallel
>   payments; do not use for chained or unilateral payments)
>
> PRIMARYRECEIVER – Primary receiver pays all fees (chained payments
>   only)
>
> EACHRECEIVER – Each receiver pays their own fee (default, personal and
>   unilateral payments)
>
> SECONDARYONLY – Secondary receivers pay all fees (use only for chained
>   payments with one secondary receiver)

Pulled from [their documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).